# Using fileupload in listview edittemplate asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview, file-upload

In a ListView edittemplate, I need to allow the user to replace an image. When the form is submitted for updating how can I determine if the user is uploading a new image and get that file info?

Thanks,

James

Comment: I just found this:

 http://rumandcode.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/aspnet-listview-with-fileupload-control-linqdatasource/ 

Would this be a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this if you want to compare file size. Granted file size comparison is not the best but FileInfo has lots of other attributes you should be able to use to make sure.

```
FileInfo oldFileInfo; // get old file's fileInfo
var tempPath = "some-temp-path-";
var tempFile = String.Format("{0}\{1}", tempPath, FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(tempFile);

FileInfo tempFileInfo = new FileInfo(tempFile);
if(tempFileInfo.Length == oldFileInfo.Length)
{
      // ask to upload a different image
}
else 
{
      // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the name off of the [FileUpload.PostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx).